# iOSアプリと外部オンラインストアとの連携はどこまでリジェクト対象となるか

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

現在iOSアプリを開発中なのですが、既存のオンラインストア（WEBアプリ）との連携機能に関して、どこまで審査のリジェクト対象になるのかについて質問があり、投稿させていただきます。

（オンラインストアは仮想的なアイテムではなく、物理的な商品（例えば時計等）を購入可能なサイトになっています。Amazonのようなサイトであるとイメージして頂いて結構です。）

1. iOSアプリ内に、オンラインストアへのリンクを貼ることはリジェクト対象か。
2. オンラインストアで購入した物理的な商品を所持している場合のみ追加される機能がiOSアプリにあるのはリジェクト対象になるか。
3. アプリ内で貯まるポイントをオンラインストアでの割引で使用するのはリジェクト対象になるか。
4. オンラインストアで貯まるポイントをアプリ内で使用するのはリジェクト対象になるか。

上記4つに関してもしご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご教授願えないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

確実なことは言えませんが、物販系については決済を外部で行うことも可能なはずです。

参考：【まとめ】iPhoneアプリ審査のリジェクト事例
http://patto-cms.jp/blog/matome_reason_for_rejecting_apps_by_apple/

> iOSアプリ内に、オンラインストアへのリンクを貼ることはリジェクト対象か。

→可能だと思います。Appleが制限したいのは課金をiTunesでさせたいためですが、ECにおいては除外しています。例としては「iQON」が似ています

> オンラインストアで購入した物理的な商品を所持している場合のみ追加される機能がiOSアプリにあるのはリジェクト対象になるか。

→ユーザーによって機能が異なるのは、問題ないと思いますが、程度にもよるかもしれません。明らかに非購入ユーザーの機能がなさすぎるような場合は、無意味なアプリとしてリジェクトされるかもしれません。

> アプリ内で貯まるポイントをオンラインストアでの割引で使用するのはリジェクト対象になるか。

→「楽天チェック」というサービスではチェックすると楽天スーパーポイントがもらえます。つまり可能そうなきがします。

> オンラインストアで貯まるポイントをアプリ内で使用するのはリジェクト対象になるか。

→これはAmazonがギフトカードを使えるので可能なはずです。

最後に、繰り返しますが申請してみないと分からないのが正直なところです。私も申請するたびに以前OKだった部分がNGにされることがありました。昔より厳しくなってきていると感じます。